# Aurelia Content Management tutorial API - Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, aurelia

I'm learning Aurelia. In following the content management tutorial, it suggested that I try to make a real API call. So, I'm trying just that.

I'm made a simple node server that returns a JSON array of objects on GET

```
// test_server.js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

var contacts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
        phoneNumber: '867-5309'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    firstName:'John',
    lastName:'Doh',
    email:'jdoh@gmail.com',
    phoneNumber:'867-5308'
  },
];

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(contacts));
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

In the `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` file, I added the following

```
"dependencies": [
  ..,
  "aurelia-http-client",
  ...
]
```

Then, I created a new web API file.

```
//new-web-api.js (es2015)
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

export class NewWebAPI {

    getAllContacts() {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.response)
                return new Promise(resolve => JSON.parse(data.response));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('failed to get a response :-(')
            });
    }
}
```

Here is the updated `contact-list.js` file,

```
// src/contact-list.js
import {NewWebAPI} from './new-web-api';

import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import {ContactUpdated, ContactViewed} from './messages';

export class ContactList {

  static inject() {
    // we declare an "inject" static method that returns an array of constructor
    // dependencies
    return [NewWebAPI, EventAggregator] 
  };

  constructor(api, ea) {
    this.api = api;
    this.contacts = [];

    /*ea.subscribe(ContactViewed, msg => this.select(msg.contact));
    ea.subscribe(ContactUpdated, msg => {
      let id = msg.contact.id;
      let found = this.contacts.find(x => x.id === id);
      Object.assign(found, msg.contact);
    });*/
  }


  created() {
    this.api.getAllContacts().then(contacts => this.contacts = contacts);
  }

  select(contact) {
    this.selectedId = contact.id;
    return true;
  }
}
```

I'm getting data back from the server (the console.log in `new-web-api` proves it.

I'm just unsure of how to return a promise to the `contact-list` module.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse` doesn't return a promise, it just returns the object parsed from the JSON, so you just need to return the parsed JSON from the promise, and then return the promise itself in `getAllContacts`. See below:

```
//new-web-api.js (es2015)
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

export class NewWebAPI {

    getAllContacts() {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        return client.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.response)
                return JSON.parse(data.response);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('failed to get a response :-(')
            });
    }
}
```

Everything else should be able to stay the same. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: ugh. so simple. It makes sense once I see it. I thought for sure I had to return a promise from within the `then`